# Get checkbox value with jQuery in .ajax data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I'm trying to pass a boolean (checked/unchecked) value with .ajax, and I can't make it work. I have read a bunch about how to get the value of a checkbox using `.is(':checked')`, vs `.prop('checked')` but I can't seem to make anything work.

Here is my HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="typeOfSearch" value="TRUE">
<label for="typeOfSearch">Exact Search?</label>
```

And here is my JavaScript

```
   $.ajax({
            url: 'partsTable.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {
                major: $('select#dropdownMajor').val(),
                minor: $('select#dropdownMinor').val(),
                typeOfSearch: $('checkbox#typeOfSearch').prop('checked')
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    var result = data
                    $('#fromPartsTable').html(result);
                }
            });
```

I can make the script work for the `select` boxes, and those continue to work after I add the checkbox, but the value of the checkbox is not being passed.

All I am interested in is passing 'checked' vs 'unchecked'.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using invalid selector. Use `input` instead.

Your HTML have `input` element,

```
<input type="checkbox" id="typeOfSearch" value="TRUE">
<label for="typeOfSearch">Exact Search?</label>
```

```js
function send() {

  $.ajax({
    url: 'partsTable.php',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {
      major: $('select#dropdownMajor').val(),
      minor: $('select#dropdownMinor').val(),
      typeOfSearch: $('input#typeOfSearch').prop('checked')
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var result = data
      $('#fromPartsTable').html(result);
    }
  });

}

$('#submit').click(function() {
  send();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly it.

Comment: @blackandorangecat glad it help you. Accept answer if helped you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't select a `checkbox` as no such tag exists. Try `input` or even giving it a unique `id` without caring about the tag e.g. `$('#typeOfSearch')`:

```js
function send() {

  $cb = $('input#typeOfSearch');
  console.log($cb.prop('checked'));

  $.ajax({
    url: 'partsTable.php',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {
      major: $('select#dropdownMajor').val(),
      minor: $('select#dropdownMinor').val(),
      typeOfSearch: $cb.prop('checked')
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var result = data
      $('#fromPartsTable').html(result);
    }
  });

}

$('#submit').click(function() {
  send();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="typeOfSearch" value="TRUE">
<label for="typeOfSearch">Exact Search?</label>
<button id="submit">Send</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Can't believe I missed that.

Comment: No problem, please choose an answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    //set initial state.
    $('#typeOfSearch').change(function() {
        $('#typeSelected').html(($(this).is(':checked') ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="typeOfSearch" /> This Type
<br>
Type Selected:
<span id="typeSelected">FALSE</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is wrong

```
$('checkbox#typeOfSearch')
```

You are looking for this:

```
<checkbox id="typeOfSearch">
```

If you just select by the id, it would work

```
$('#typeOfSearch')
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 1):

The below are some of the ways you can see if the checkbox is checked. If the checkbox is checked the value is true or else it is false.

```
if ($('#typeOfSearch:checked').length > 0) {
    /* Do something */
}

if($('#typeOfSearch').prop('checked') == true) {
    /* Do something */
}

if ($('#typeOfSearch').filter(':checked')) {
    /* Do something */
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please search better when asking Stack Overflow questions. This was the top hit on Google for "jquery get checked or unchecked":

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27265333/5129424

Your selector will only attach event to element which are selected in the beginning. You need to determine check unchecked state when value is changed:

```
 $("#countries input:checkbox").change(function() {
                    var ischecked= $(this).is(':checked');
                    if(!ischecked)
                      alert('uncheckd ' + $(this).val());
                });
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b0uu7ja4/)