# how can we write an unchecked event for checkbox in jquery?. like we do for checked event?

Tags: jquery

i tried below with checked event

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.same').change(function(){
    if(this.checked){
      alert("checked");
    }
  });
});
```

i did this for checked event, how can i do same for the unchecked event..

Comment: add `else` part

Comment: i did that one and i don't want that to happen.. by default its checked, if i uncheck means then it should do some operation.

Comment: for checking i had given  this.checked  in if statement, is there any statements there i can give   this.unchecked   ?..

Comment: yes `!this.checked`. check the answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27265308/jquery-how-get-checkbox-unchecked-event-and-checkbox-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***If you want only `unchecked` event then do `!this.checked` like below:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.same').change(function(){
    if(!this.checked){
      alert("unchecked");
    }
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="same">Check/Uncheck me to see the alerts!
```

***If you want both `checked/unchecked` event then you can use `else` part there:-***

Example:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.same').change(function(){
    if(this.checked){
      alert("checked");
    }else{
      alert("unchecked");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="same">Check/Uncheck me to see the alerts!
```

Comment: Hi bro.. i tried with else part it works.. i tried previously with else part only, that time it was not working then i cleared cookies and now its working fine.. thank you..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if( !this.checked ){
```

here `! not` is used with checked, that means it is referring to unchecked. Or you can use `else` as @Alive suggested.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.same').change(function(){
                if(!this.checked){
                       alert("not checked");
                 }
       });
 });
```

Just use ! this.checked